# Increase row height of datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, multiline

I want DataGridView to display data from database in multi-line, and I have coded like

```
Grid.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
Grid.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
```

but once this property has been set I cannot increase row height of gridview's row using

```
Grid.Rows[1].Height =Grid.Rows[1].Height +  40;
```

any idea about how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

remove `Grid.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;` and auto size by code

```
for (int i = 0; i < this.dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
   if(i =1 )
   {
      this.dataGridView1.Rows[1].Height =Grid.Rows[1].Height +  40;
   }elese
   {
      this.dataGridView1.AutoResizeRow(i);
   }
}
```

Comment: That works fine.
but is there any way i can cancel 
Grid.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
property on any single row so that i need not to move through all rows as database contains huge amount of data?

Comment: are you going to load all the data in to grid view? it is not a good way. use paging and limit no of records per page.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you toggle this off / back to default:

```
Grid.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
```

after getting the height value and then setting the height?

Comment: then multiline is lost for other cells.and i don't want that.